# Asymptotics of Riemann Zeta function

Tags: asymptotics, riemann-zeta

In Titchmarsh Theorem 4.11 we find that for $s=\sigma+it$

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}+O\left(\frac1{x^\sigma}\right),$$
when $|t|<\frac{2\pi x}{c}, c>1, \sigma>0$.

I am interested in the approximation of $\zeta$ function when $t=0$. So, am I correct to understand that
$$\zeta(\sigma)=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n^\sigma}-\frac{x^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma}+O\left(\frac1{x^\sigma}\right)?$$

Comment: That seems correct to me.

Comment: Why not check the proof ? For $\Re(s) > 0$ $$\zeta(s) - \frac{1}{s-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^{-s} - \int_n^{n+1} x^{-s}dx )= \sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s} -\int_1^{N+1} x^{-s}dx + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} \int_n^x s u^{-s-1}dudx$$